# MySql SELECT MATCH AGAINST combined with a WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently building a search engine using MySQL to return data about users registered in a website. The SQL being used is as follows:

```
SELECT id, username, country, profession, company
FROM users
WHERE MATCH(username, country, profession, company) AGAINST ('+query' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

So far, so good. What I also want is for the search engine to not return data about users whose account is inactive. There is a column in the table with the name 'inactive'. If the corresponding account is inactive, the 'inactive' field for the respective account has the value 'Y'. All active accounts have 'N' instead.

I tried to build a query similar to the one above but also adding a "WHERE inactive='N'" clause at the very end of it.

```
SELECT id, username, country, profession, company
FROM users
WHERE (MATCH(username, country, profession, company) AGAINST ('+query' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND (WHERE inactive='N')
```

Unfortunately, an error is returned. Can someone help me with the syntax?

Comment: The second `WHERE` in your query is a syntax error.  I'm voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Can you specify how to correct my syntax error?

Comment: Remove the where in AND (WHERE inactive='N')

Comment: Solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The query was amended with the following syntax:

```sql
SELECT id, username, country, profession, company
FROM users
WHERE (MATCH(username, country, profession, company) AGAINST ('+query' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND (inactive='N')
```

It worked. The only amendment done was the removal of the second WHERE.